# What does __init__ do in python?

Tags: python, programming-languages, init, coderunner

What does **init** in python language

I was learning the python language and I am facing difficulty to understand **init** it. I tried to search about this on google but I am not cleared about this.

Comment: What is not clear about the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames:~:text=object.__init__(self%5B%2C%20...%5D) ?  Can you provide an example with an unclear output?

Answer (score 0):

the **init** function is called everytime an object is created from a class. The **init** method lets the class initialize the object's attributes and serves no other purpose

Answer (score 0):

In python, __ init __ is the keyword for creating a constructor of a class.

For example,

```
class Person:
        
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
        
        def introduce(self):
            print(f"Hi, I am {self.name}")
```

You can also create a file named as __ init __.py in a directory of python scripts/files in order to make it a python module.

Comment: `__init__` is not a *keyword*, a method named thusly also isn't a *constructor*. These words have defined meanings, and not the meaning you ascribe.